# Dotted route when travel mode for driving is not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am trying to make the route for my map in ionic, and I can't seem to find a way to show the route as dotted when the travel mode for driving is not available - like on the google maps.

This is how my maps route looks like:
[without the dotted route ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSUTa.png)

This is how google maps route looks like:
[with the dotted route ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ootUp.png)

This is how the code for the route looks like for now:

```
    function route(travel_mode, directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    console.log($scope.transfer.origin.place_id, $scope.transfer.destination.place_id);
    if (!$scope.transfer.origin.place_id || !$scope.transfer.destination.place_id) {
      return;
    }
    else if (ok == 0) {
      ok = 1;
      directionsService.route({
        origin: {
          'placeId': $scope.transfer.origin.place_id
        }
        , destination: {
          'placeId': $scope.transfer.destination.place_id
        }
        , travelMode: travel_mode
      }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          var origin1 = $scope.transfer.origin.place_title;
          var destinationA = $scope.transfer.destination.place_title;
          console.dir(origin1);
          var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
          service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [origin1]
            , destinations: [destinationA]
            , travelMode: 'DRIVING'
            , unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
          }, callback);
          function callback(response, status) {
            console.dir(response);
            if (status == 'OK') {
              origins = response.originAddresses[0];
              destinations = response.destinationAddresses[0];
              results = response.rows[0].elements[0];
              distance = results.distance.text;
              duration = results.duration.text;
              DTransfer.setData('distance', distance);
              DTransfer.setData('duration', duration);
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

If there is any fix, can anybody help?

Comment: Google Maps JavaScript API doesn't have this feature. Probably you can raise the feature request in public [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/). As a workaround you can analyze the JSON response to find the last point of the route and draw a polyline between the last point and your coordinate.

Comment: @xomena I figured a way around it, thank you.
I used: var line = new google.maps.Polyline and i created a path from my final destination to my destination coord icon and it kind of works. Thank you!